# How to fix Method 'initialize()' defines Objective-C class method 'initialize', which is not permitted by Swift in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift4, iqkeyboardmanager

I am updating my app from Swift 3 to Swift 4 and after migration, there are a few errors. One of them is `Method 'initialize()' defines Objective-C class method 'initialize', which is not permitted by Swift` in IQToolbar of `IQKeyboardManager`, how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**- You can also use Singleton solve this problem such as:**

```
    static let shared : AudioTools = {
           $0.initialize()
           return $0
       }(AudioTools())
```

**Your Objective-C method--->initialize**

```
override class func initialize(){code here}
```

change:

```
func initialize(){code here}
```

**Your method here:**

```
func playSound(fileName:String?) {
       code here
    }
```

**use in Swift3:**

```
let audioPlayer = AudioTools.playMusic(fileName: fileName)
```

**use in Swift4**

```
let audioPlayer = AudioTools.shared.playMusic(fileName: fileName)
```

Comment: I've answered in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46360311/1581772

Where I show you can use a singleton (like @user8152635 does) or where you can use a public static method