# IOS Swizzling the best newest way to do it today

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, newrelic, swizzling

We have an IOS swift code that is doing swizzling by using method_exchangeimplementations
But this a method since 2014
And it is causing our app to crash when using new relic.

Is there a newer better way to do it today in year 2022?

I read about _dynamicreplacement
But is it working the same?
Is there something else?
What's the best newest way to do swizzling today?

Comment: Here you can check a previous similar question. Take care making questions, try to add some code about what you have already tested to make other users easier to help. Check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70025447/4577504