# What is the equivalent of + (void)load {} in Swift 4?

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Objective-C, we have:

```
+(void)load
{

}
```

What is the equivalent of this in Swift 4?

In Swift **1**, we have:

```
override class func load() {

}
```

...but it's not available in Swift 4.2.

Comment: There is no equivalent func in Swift4

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/29104893/1187415: *"Support for overriding load was removed in Swift 1.2"*

Comment: There is none as far as I know, all global initialization must somehow be done explicitly. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824541/swift-3-1-deprecates-initialize-how-can-i-achieve-the-same-thing for a related discussion. – This https://stackoverflow.com/a/47621197/1187415 might help (i.e. use an Objective-C helper class), I don't know if that still works or is guaranteed to work in the future.

Comment: @MartinR there is Magic in ObjC like `+(void)load
{
    NSLog(@"Gott");
}` which is not dependent to initialzie, or anything, it invokes automatically.  I am just looking the same in swift thanks btw :) .

Comment: I know what that does in Objective-C, but that feature does not exist in Swift.